# How can i resolve the N+1 Selects problem?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have trouble understanding how to avoid the n+1 select in jpa or hibernate.

From what i read, there's the 'left join fetch', but i'm not sure if it still works with more than one list (oneToMany)..

Could someone explain it to me, or give me a link with a clear complete explanation please ?

I'm sorry if this is a noob question, but i can't find a real clear article or doc on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Understanding this problem is crucial for working with Hibernate. I have even developed a small librry for identiying this issue in unit tests:
https://github.com/bedrin/jdbc-sniffer/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the join, you can also use subselect(s). This results in 2 queries being executed (or in general *m* + 1, if you have *m* lists), but it scales well for a large number of lists too, unlike join fetching.

With join fetching, if you fetch 2 tables (or lists) with your entity, you get a *cartesian product*, i.e. all combinations of pairs of rows from the two tables. If the tables are large, the result can be *huge*, e.g. if both tables have 1000 rows, the cartesian product contains 1 million rows!

A better alternative for such cases is to use subselects. In this case, you would issue 2 selects - one for each table - on top of the main select (which loads the parent entity), so altogether you load 1 + 100 + 100 rows with 3 queries.

For the record, the same with lazy loading would result in 201 separate selects, each loading a single row.

**Update:** here are some examples:

- a tutorial: [Tuning Lazy Fetching](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91885142.html), with a section on subselects towards the end (btw it also explains the n+1 selects problem and all strategies to deal with it),
- [examples of HQL subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries) from the Hibernate reference,
- just in case, [the chapter on fetching strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) from the Hibernate reference - similar content as the first one, but much more thorough

Comment: could you provide a short hql example for the subselects solution ? it would help me figure it out i think. Thanks :)

Comment: @Maxime I added some links, hope these help :-)